# Angular promise should call other promises

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, promise, angularjs-routing

I have a state which resolves as :

```
resolve: {
              accounts: function(utils) {
                return utils.getAccounts();
              },
              data: function(utils) {
                return utils.getData();
              },
              termsData: function(utils) {
                return utils.getTerms();
              }
            }
```

I need to make sure that `data` and `termsData` are called only after `accounts` is returned in angular `resolve`.

getAccounts function looke like :

```
 function getAccounts() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            Restangular.setBaseUrl(baseUrl());
            var accountsService = Restangular.all(accountsUrl);
            accountsService.post({headers}).then(function(data) {
              deferred.resolve(data);
            }, function(ex) {
              deferred.reject(ex);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
          }
```

Comment: Avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Comment: @theConstructor does any of answer helped you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add accounts as a dependency the same way like I suppose you do in controller:

```
resolve: {
          accounts: function(utils) {
            return utils.getAccounts();
          },
          data: ['accounts', 'utils', function(accounts, utils) {
              accounts.then(function(data){
                 return utils.getData();
              }, function(data){
                 return $q.reject();
              });
          }]
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do call other two once `getAccounts` function promise get resolved and then do return data with `getData` & `getTerms` promise with `$q.all`.

```
resolve: {
    accounts: function(utils, $q) {
        return utils.getAccounts().then(function(accounts){
            return $q.all([accounts, utils.getData(), utils.getTerms()])
        });
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($q, $scope, accounts){
    console.log("accounts", accounts[0])
    console.log("getData Response", accounts[1])
    console.log("getTerms Response", accounts[2])
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you need to get all your data asynchronously you can simply restructure your code to take advantage of the promise pattern.

```
var getAccounts = function(...) {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
    ... do something and resolve or reject
  };
};

var getTermsData = funciton= function(...) {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
    ... do something and resolve or reject
  };
};

var getData = = function(...) {
  return new Promise(resolve, reject) {
    ... do something and resolve or reject
  };
};

getAccounts.then(function(accounts) {
  return getTermData();
}.then(function(termData) {
  return getData(data);
}.catch(function() {
  // something went wrong!
}
```